# Inconsistent weights with Lumley's survey package (svyglm vs svyolr). Error or by design?

Tags: r, regression, survey, weighted

My main goal is conducting mediation (using the `mediation` R package) while accounting for sampling weights (using the `survey` package). This led me to discover that weights are stored differently for models fit with `survey::svyglm` and for models fit with `survey::svyolr`.

```
set.seed(3459823)

library(survey)
library(srvyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(mediation)

n <- 100

# simulate data
dat <- tibble::tibble(
  id = 1:100,
  y_binary = sample(c(0,1), size = n, replace = TRUE),
  m_binary = sample(c(0,1), size = n, replace = TRUE),
  m_ordinal = sample(c(1, 2, 3), size = n, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.5)) |> 
    as.factor() |> 
    as.ordered(),
  pred_normal = rnorm(n = n),
  weight = rnorm(n = n, mean = 15),
  weight_rep1 = rnorm(n = n, mean = weight),
  weight_rep2 = rnorm(n = n, mean = weight),
  weight_rep3 = rnorm(n = n, mean = weight),
  weight_rep4 = rnorm(n = n, mean = weight),
  weight_rep5 = rnorm(n = n, mean = weight)
)

# create design object
dat_design <- dat |> 
  srvyr::as_survey_rep(
    repweights = dplyr::contains("_rep"),
    weights = weight,
    combined_weights = TRUE
  )

# ordinal mediator models
model_y_binary <- survey::svyglm(
  formula = y_binary ~ m_ordinal + pred_normal, 
  design = dat_design, 
  family = "binomial"
)

model_m_ordinal <- survey::svyolr(
  formula = m_ordinal ~ pred_normal, 
  design = dat_design
)

mediation_ordinal <- mediation::mediate(
  model.m = model_m_ordinal,
  model.y = model_y_binary,
  sims = 50,
  treat = "pred_normal",
  mediator = "m_ordinal"
)

# Won't run!
# Error in mediation::mediate(model.m = model_m_ordinal, model.y = model_y_binary,  : 
#   weights on outcome and mediator models not identical
```

I then inspected the weights saved in the model objects using the `model.frame()` function, which is also what `mediation::mediate` seems to use under the hood to extract the weights.

```
# Inspecting the weights saved by the survey models:

model.frame(model_y_binary) |> dplyr::slice_head()

# Result:
#   y_binary m_ordinal pred_normal (weights)
# 1        1         3 -0.09479119  1.004946

# so, the binomial model stores the weights in a column in the model.frame

model.frame(model_m_ordinal) |> dplyr::slice_head()

# Result:
#   m_ordinal pred_normal (weights)
# 1         3 -0.09479119  14.92443

# so, the ordinal model stores the weight as well, but they are different!

weight_comparison <- tibble::tibble(
  binomial_weights = model.frame(model_y_binary)$`(weights`,
  ordinal_weights = model.frame(model_m_ordinal)$`(weights)`,
  weight_quotient = binomial_weights / ordinal_weights
)

weight_comparison |> dplyr::slice_head(n = 5)

# Result:
#   binomial_weights ordinal_weights weight_quotient
#              <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>
# 1            1.00             14.9          0.0673
# 2            1.03             15.2          0.0673
# 3            0.992            14.7          0.0673
# 4            1.01             14.9          0.0673
# 5            0.927            13.8          0.0673

# so, all the binomial weights seem to be equal to the ordinal weights times ~0.0673
```

Why does this happen?

Is there a way to alter the fit `survey::svyolr` model object and force the weights to be equal to those stored in the `svyglm` model object?

Could the `mediation` package be altered to take this into account? For example by just taking the weights from model.m and not comparing them to model.y? (Of course this could also lead to other problems.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some functions in the survey package rescale the weights to have unit mean because the large weights (thousands or tens of thousands) in some national surveys can cause convergence problems.

Since the results aren't affected at all, the `mediate` package could probably work around this fairly easily.  However, there's a `rescale=FALSE` option to `svyglm` to not rescale the weights, provided for this sort of purpose.

If you then have convergence problems in `svyglm` you could manually rescale the weights to have unit mean before doing any of the analyses.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. Can you tell me more about rescaling the weights manually prior to model fitting? What formula can I use for the weights and the replicate weights? 
Do I simply divide each column of weights by that column's mean?
I tried finding out by looking at the source code for svyglm but was not successful.

Comment: I've done just that (dat |> mutate(weight = weight/mean(weight))), for the replicate weights as well, and it seems to work! But now I realize mediation package does not work yet with svyolr models anyway, so I'll probably just have to conduct the mediation without using sampling weights.